# How can we use Content type with DD4T experience manager implementation

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, dd4t

I have created a content type and added it to a page. Content of that type is not showing to edit and insert content. Can anyone suggest how can I edit the content type created and inserted on a page? Yes, Component with that CT is already showing on the page. Reason for that seems that, on page view I have not used that content type. Code for my page view is as below:

```
<section class="txt" role="txt">
    <figure id="box" class="Container">
        @Html.RenderComponentPresentationsByView("ComponentView")
    </figure>
</section>
@Html.SiteEditPage(Model);
```

Isn't it require to handle content type in the page view code?

Thanks.
Mukesh

Comment: Can you elaborate (in your question) on what the problem is? You define content types against the Page Template in the CME as described [here](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_882FF93B152F4C879FFA7F8CAA21ED2D) - I'm not sure why DD4T would cause you a problem?

Comment: Indeed, doesn't seem to be related to DD4T at all

Comment: Actually, I have created the content type in CME. Then created the component based on that inside siteedit UI. Inserted it on the page. But now I can't see that newly created component inside siteedit to modify and insert content in that.
It is not showing on Page.

Comment: Does your DD4T page render Component Presentations using that Component Template? Have you disabled caching on your DD4T website? Is the session preview up to date? You need to add much more detail on what you are doing and what the problem is to your question (including any relevant screenshots or code). It is hard to help you when you are so vague.

Comment: Hi AntP,

I have added page view code snippet in my question. Please suggest now..

Thanks.
Mukesh

Comment: Can you answer the rest of my questions too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Page Type/Content Type is a feature of CMS which can be effectively used in the Experience Manager. For such scenario, I suggest to check following

- Check by opening the page (through CME or XPM) whether the Content inserted from the XPM is associated as expected in the page
- If it is associated with the page as expected, then check in publishing queue whether it has been published successfully
- If it is published well and reloading of the page is also working fine (without any error in the notification area), then I a quite sure that it is something related to your HTML (or whatever Code) issue. Verify by publishing the page from CME and verify on the browser if it is working fine or not.

I hope it helps.